# Save a line only if not matched

Tags: php

I'm trying to save data from file in case the line is not matched with a character.
In my case, I have a list of numbers, I want to save these numbers if only the first character is not equal to "0" -zero-

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$cleanfile = "cleanfile.txt";
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($line[0] != 0) {
            $save = file_put_contents($cleanfile, $line);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

My file.txt has the following entries:

```
1
2
3457
94
31
54
039
3114
94
01
33333
1
2
3457
94
31
54
039
3114
94
01
33333
1
2
3457
94
31
54
039
3114
94
01
33333
```

Comment: Tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: It's not saving actually entries that do not start with 0, it only saves "01" in cleanfile.txt

Comment: So it's like if this condition is not doing it if ($line[0] != 0)

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php): _If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `FILE_APPEND` flag to `file_put_contents()`, like this:

```
<?php
$cleanfile = "cleanfile.txt";
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($line[0] != 0) {
            $save = file_put_contents($cleanfile, $line, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

However, your solution is a little resource-hungry, since every call to `file_put_contents()` generates unnecessary overhead. Please consider this demo as a lighter, more compact solution:

```
<?php

// Collect all non-filtered lines.
$sieved = [];
// Read file.txt into an array, skipping empty lines.
foreach (file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line)
{
        if ($line[0] !== '0')
                $sieved[] = $line;
}

// Write out each array element, keeping the newlines from the input.
file_put_contents('cleanfile.txt', $sieved);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to upvote but it says that I need like 15 reputation.. I accepted it instead :)

Answer (score 0):

For fun, unless the files are enormous this should work.  Read the file into an array, grep for lines not starting with `0` and write it out to the new file:

```
file_put_contents("cleanfile.txt", preg_grep('/^[^0]/', file("file.txt")));
```

You could replace the grep with a filter:

```
array_filter(file("file.txt"), function($v) { return ($v[0] != 0); })
```